# Nested or multiple select_for_updates

Tags: django, orm, select-for-update

I wish to acquire locks on more than one unrelated object using `.select_for_update`.  Do I need to wrap each call with a `transaction.atomic`?  I've read the sections in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) and postgres' [Row Locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS) but it's unclear on the matter.

```py
from django.db import models


class A(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField()


class B(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField()
```

This is a bit of a contrived example, but given the above models, can I do this?

```py
def update_records(pk_a, pk_b, value):
    with transaction.atomic():
        a_object = A.objects.get(pk=pk_a).select_for_update()
        b_object = B.objects.get(pk=pk_b).select_for_update()
        # modify values, etc
```

or do I need to do this?

```py
def update_records(pk_a, pk_b, value):
    with transaction.atomic():
        a_object = A.objects.get(pk=pk_a).select_for_update()
        with transaction.atomic():
            b_object = B.objects.get(pk=pk_b).select_for_update()
```